# Non-parseable POM spring boot maven project

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I know that this is duplicate question. But any answer of the previous questions does not help me. 
I have created very simple spring boot project in eclipse. Its is every thing okay running in linux. But in windows its the following error in the first line of pom.xml.

```
Project build error: Non-parseable POM 
C:\Users\DELL\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-bom\4.1.25.Final\netty-bom- 
4.1.25.Final.pom: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserved 
xml name (position: END_TAG seen ...</dependencyManagement>\n</project>\n<? 
xml ... @236:7)
```

And when run the following error

```
C:\Users\DELL\eclipse-workspace\demo>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\maven-repo\repository\io\netty\netty-bom\4.1.25.Final\netty-bom-4.1.25.Final.pom: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserved xml name (position: END_TAG seen ...</dependencyManagement>\n</project>\n<?xml ... @236:7)  @ C:\maven-repo\repository\io\netty\netty-bom\4.1.25.Final\netty-bom-4.1.25.Final.pom, line 236, column 7
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.springboot:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\DELL\eclipse-workspace\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\maven-repo\repository\io\netty\netty-bom\4.1.25.Final\netty-bom-4.1.25.Final.pom: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserved xml name (position: END_TAG seen ...</dependencyManagement>\n</project>\n<?xml ... @236:7)  @ C:\maven-repo\repository\io\netty\netty-bom\4.1.
25.Final\netty-bom-4.1.25.Final.pom, line 236, column 7 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]<br>
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

I have tried about three day for this but now I have no idea how to solve this error. Someone help me please.

Comment: Remove your local cache before you rebuild turn on checksum policy checking and rebuild...

Comment: @khmarbaise Could you explain why the error is occured please?

Comment: My assumption is that a network/proxy/firewall issue files have not been downloaded correctly which results in corrupted files...which can cause such issues...